# HDMI device detected by the system but not listed. Which is the package affected by this bug?

Tags: 12.04, bug-reporting

I would like to report this bug, but I can't figure out what package is affected.

It is certainly just a graphical matter because using `hardinfo`, running `pacmd` or trying to switch to HDMI in XBMC works, it's just not listed in *System Settings* -> *Sound*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by filing a bug on `gnome-control-center`, it can be moved to a different package if necessary, this would be done by a triager. While it's very helpful to get the package right on the first try (much appreciated, thanks!) it's not mandatory, and as a bug gets investigated it can naturally change packages.

Comment: Thank you very much, I followed your advice and reported the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/961286)